# Rigid registration of two point clouds with known correspondence

Tags: python

Imagine I have two (python) lists (with a limited) amount of 3D points. How do I find a rigid transformation to match the points as closely as possible. For each point of each list it is known to which other point that point corresponds. Is there an algorithm/library for this?

I found the Iterative closest point algorithm, but this assumes there is no correspondence known and it seems to be made for large point clouds. I'm talking about limited sets of 3 to 8 points.

Possible point sets (correspondence according to index in the list)

```
a = [[0,0,0], [1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
b = [[0,0,0.5], [1,0,1],[0,0,2]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out there is actually an analytical solution. It is described in the paper of [Arun et al., 1987, Least square fitting of two 3D point sets](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4767965)

I wrote a testscript to test their algorithm and it seems to work fine (if you want to have a solution that minimizes the sum of the square errors, if you have an outlier this might not be ideal):

```
import numpy as np

##Based on Arun et al., 1987

#Writing points with rows as the coordinates
p1_t = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
p2_t = np.array([[0,0,1], [1,0,1],[0,0,2]]) #Approx transformation is 90 degree rot over x-axis and +1 in Z axis

#Take transpose as columns should be the points
p1 = p1_t.transpose()
p2 = p2_t.transpose()

#Calculate centroids
p1_c = np.mean(p1, axis = 1).reshape((-1,1)) #If you don't put reshape then the outcome is 1D with no rows/colums and is interpeted as rowvector in next minus operation, while it should be a column vector
p2_c = np.mean(p2, axis = 1).reshape((-1,1))

#Subtract centroids
q1 = p1-p1_c
q2 = p2-p2_c

#Calculate covariance matrix
H=np.matmul(q1,q2.transpose())

#Calculate singular value decomposition (SVD)
U, X, V_t = np.linalg.svd(H) #the SVD of linalg gives you Vt

#Calculate rotation matrix
R = np.matmul(V_t.transpose(),U.transpose())

assert np.allclose(np.linalg.det(R), 1.0), "Rotation matrix of N-point registration not 1, see paper Arun et al."

#Calculate translation matrix
T = p2_c - np.matmul(R,p1_c)

#Check result
result = T + np.matmul(R,p1)
if np.allclose(result,p2):
    print("transformation is correct!")
else:
    print("transformation is wrong...")
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this more recent algorithm: J. Cashbaugh and C. Kitts, "Automatic Calculation of a Transformation Matrix Between Two Frames," in IEEE Access, vol. 6, pp. 9614-9622, 2018, doi: 10.1109/ACCESS.2018.2799173.

Here is the Python code replicating the example in the paper. I doesn't get much more concise:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.5449, 0.1955, 0.9227], [0.6862, 0.7202, 0.8004], [0.8936, 0.7218, 0.2859],
              [0.0548, 0.8778, 0.5437], [0.3037, 0.5824, 0.9848], [0.0462, 0.0707, 0.7157]])
b = np.array([[2.5144, 7.0691, 1.9754], [2.8292, 7.4454, 2.2224], [3.3518, 7.3060, 2.1198],
              [2.8392, 7.8455, 1.6229], [2.4901, 7.5449, 1.9518], [2.4273, 7.1354, 1.4349]])

a1 = np.column_stack((a,np.ones(a.shape[0])))
b1 = np.column_stack((b,np.ones(b.shape[0])))

matrixA = np.tensordot(a1,a1.T,axes=[0,1])
matrixR = np.tensordot(a1,b1.T,axes=[0,1])
matrixAinv = np.linalg.inv(matrixA)

tm = np.tensordot(matrixAinv,matrixR,axes=1).transpose() 
errors = b1 - [tm @ x for x in a1]
mean_error = np.mean([np.linalg.norm(y) for y in errors])  # 0.0109002
sum_error = np.sum([np.linalg.norm(y) for y in errors])  # 0.0654013

# print('\nA (23)\n',np.array2string(matrixA, precision=8))
# print('\n(20-22)\n',np.array2string(matrixR, precision=8))
print('\nT (24)\n',np.array2string(tm, precision=4, suppress_small=True))
print(f'Mean Error: {mean_error:.3f}')
print(f'Sum Error:  {sum_error:.3f}')
print(f'Froebenius: {np.linalg.norm(errors):.3f}')
```